# how to restrict a ldap user from login In wso2 Identity server oauth2/openid

Tags: oauth-2.0, ldap, wso2, openid, wso2-identity-server

I need to restrict a ldap user account from logging in oauth2 token authentication. I could not find any configuration for its service provider configuration. By default, all ldap users are getting logged in by the wso2 identity server. Need help to sort this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is no any configuration for this. Currently any user who are connected using user stores to WSO2IS, can login with SSO.  For management console login,  user must have the `login` permission.  If you need to restrict the user for SSO login, you need to customize the default SSO authenticator of WSO2IS.

If you are using `authorization code` grant type,  it means that you are using SSO login for OAuth2.  But if you are using `password` grant type,  you need to customize the grant handler to limit the user login. Details about customizing grant type can be found from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/20/custom-grant-type-with-oauth/)

Comment: Thanks asela. Answers helps